# Convert MP3 to WAV on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can I convert MP3 file to WAV file on WP8?
Is there an API or do I need to use 3rd party code?

The need for WAV files results from the fact that my application plays prompts to the user from time to time. In order not to terminate audio from background applications I have to use the SoundEffect class. This class can only handle WAV files.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not convert your MP3s to WAV on your PC then?

Comment: Maybe he simple wants to do in app.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work on WP8 but you can try it.

In WPF, I use NAudio. You can add it to your project via nuget.

After, you can use the following snippet :

```
    public static void Mp3ToWav(string mp3File, string outputFile)
    {
        using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3File))
        {
            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputFile, reader);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot use NAudio for windows phone.

Comment: No portable class lib yet: http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/naudio-17-release-notes.html (http://naudio.codeplex.com/) You can contact mark (http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.nl/p/about-me.html) or try to build the pcl from the codeplex source yourself